# Using Devise in a Mountable Engine Rails from outside of the engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I have an engine called hq_core, and I have another rails app called hq.

hq_core has a devise user installed within it and it works perfectly from hq.  I did this using [this how-to](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine)

I want to create a devise admin_user that is only in hq, not hq_core.  I ran the typical 'rails g devise admin_user' which installed find in hq.

But when I hit localhost:3000/admin_users/sign_in, it says

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `admin_user_session_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x007fb454403818>):
```

This is a rails 4 application with Devise 3.0.0rc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem which I solved by adding

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.router_name = :<your engine name here>
end
```

to my config/initializers/devise.rb as stated in the how to.